# PHP timeout concept

Tags: php, web-services, timeout

I have a question for all the PHP folks

If I have a PHP execution timeout set to 30 seconds

and if the script calls a webservice, and the timeout for the web service is 60 seconds. Will I get a execution timeout error after 30 seconds?

Comment: The best way to answer this question is to tell you to, try it yourself. But it is more of a common sense actually as web service also run on PHP.

Comment: Yep! Use `set_time_limit` to remedy that. There's also `default_socket_timeout` to take in to consideration here.